# What's the meaning of linguistics?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, functional-programming, computational-linguistics

In the programming language theory world, there are two important terminologies, i.e syntax, and semantics.

I can understand these two terminologies:

**syntax** is about sentence's structure (e.g. a valid sentence by some grammar)

**semantics** is about sentence's meaning (e.g. operational semantics, denotational semantics, etc)

But recently the third word appeared in some PL papers i.e. **linguistics**, although it is very rare.

What's the meaning of linguistics?

What's the relationship between linguistics and syntax/semantics ?

Thanks.

PS: I'm sorry, I don't know whether it’s suitable to post this question here, because my vision is very narrow...

---

The following are some PL papers that used this term:

[https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/~robby/pubs/papers/aplas2006-fff.pdf](https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/%7Erobby/pubs/papers/aplas2006-fff.pdf)

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.8118&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Note that this is not a temporary question. The word "linguistic(s)" is not just appeared in these two papers. It also appeared in other papers, but I can't remember all (sorry). Failure to understand the "linguistic(s)" does not affect the understanding of the paper. I am just curious about the meaning of the "linguistic(s)".

Comment: In both papers it appears only in the abstract, so I doubt it's important to understand. Anyway, I guess by "linguistic constructs" they probably mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_construct

Comment: @Dmitry As I mentioned above, failure to understand the "linguistic(s)" does not affect the understanding of those papers. But if I can understand the precise definition of this term, then I can use it in my own articles confidently.

Comment: Both linked papers use adjective “linguistic”, which is just a proper way to say “languagy”. But your question is about a noun. Do you have examples that use the noun “linguistics”?

Comment: Linguistics is the scientific study of language, and its focus is the systematic investigation of the properties of particular languages as well as the characteristics of language in general.